# Is this patent approved and valid?

Tags: us20090303320

I am thinking of making my own product. Twizzers with Camera that transmit video image to cell-phone.

Is this patent valid ?

Comment: While this patent may be granted, your idea 1) may not infringe and 2) may still be patentable. You should, however, be careful with how much you information you disclose online.

Answer (score 1):

You referred to the patent application publication.  The patent issued as U.S. Patent No. 8,427,535 on April 23, 2013.